# 18.04: VPN fails on a specific WiFi connection in Ubuntu, works OK in Windows

Tags: networking, dual-boot, 18.04, vpn

I live in a country which unfortunately filters and blocks many websites, so I use VPN.

Recently I encountered a problem with a university WiFi connection when using VPN in my Ubuntu 18.04; although the VPN app (which I got from the VPN provider) connects to their server, the blocked websites (e.g., YouTube) are still blocked!

The same VPN over my Windows system works correctly!

I thought that it might be from my browser so I pinged some blocked websites but they don't work.

How can I troubleshoot this?

**UPDATE**
I just found out that my vpn doesnt change my ip address when connected!I tested this with multiple ip finder webistes.also here are the contents of my `ifconfig` command before and after connection:

```
anbox0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.250.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::66:12ff:fee3:ffb5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:5d:80:e1:16:9c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 146  bytes 13939 (13.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 251  bytes 63006 (63.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp2s0f2: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 4c:ed:fb:2b:2c:f1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 15105  bytes 80728490 (80.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 15105  bytes 80728490 (80.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ppp0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1400
        inet 194.225.42.180  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 172.17.1.218
        ppp  txqueuelen 3  (Point-to-Point Protocol)
        RX packets 48702  bytes 30888989 (30.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 48540  bytes 7206273 (7.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vethUQITES: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::fc5d:80ff:fee1:169c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:5d:80:e1:16:9c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 146  bytes 15983 (15.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 244  bytes 61931 (61.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.16  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::1919:c8a3:32c:f446  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 50:5b:c2:09:cf:95  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 719368  bytes 653900335 (653.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 643015  bytes 88976193 (88.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

after:

```
anbox0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.250.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::66:12ff:fee3:ffb5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:5d:80:e1:16:9c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 146  bytes 13939 (13.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 251  bytes 63006 (63.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp2s0f2: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 4c:ed:fb:2b:2c:f1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 15115  bytes 80730702 (80.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 15115  bytes 80730702 (80.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ppp0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1400
        inet 194.225.42.180  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 172.17.1.218
        ppp  txqueuelen 3  (Point-to-Point Protocol)
        RX packets 48760  bytes 30903272 (30.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 48594  bytes 7212817 (7.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vethUQITES: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::fc5d:80ff:fee1:169c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:5d:80:e1:16:9c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 146  bytes 15983 (15.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 244  bytes 61931 (61.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vpn0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1334
        inet 192.168.14.80  netmask 255.255.248.0  destination 192.168.14.80
        inet6 fe80::108a:ae7e:42f3:a509  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 500  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 4  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1  bytes 48 (48.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.16  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::1919:c8a3:32c:f446  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 50:5b:c2:09:cf:95  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 719427  bytes 653917820 (653.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 643093  bytes 88988312 (88.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Have you contacted your VPN provider for help? Maybe the Linux version of their VPN client is not as up to date as the Windows VPN client. Also, make sure the settings of the Linux VPN client are the same as the Windows VPN client.

Comment: @K7AAY the thing is it worked properly a couple of days ago and now it doesn't work.I also tested a chrome extension for changing my ip and it did work! so the problem is not the network itslef...

Comment: IT folks are adding new ways to block information daily. It's not a problem I face here, thanks be to the Great Bird of the Galaxy, so I don't have the level of expertise you need.

Comment: @K7AAY this website doesn't work...

Comment: What you showed above is what the OS finds for your IP addresses. Please go to http://ipchicken.com from both Windows and Ubuntu with their respective VPNs enabled, and tell us what that site reports.

Answer (score 1):

Do a traceroute to the address of the site you are interested to reach, to see which path are you connecting through:

```
traceroute -n 8.8.8.8
```

You may need to add a default rout through the VPN adapter, please see: [How to route all traffic through vpn adapter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065397/how-to-route-all-traffic-through-vpn-adapter)